# System.Text.Json Constructor and immutable type

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, system.text.json

I have a lot of immutable DTOs which I need to deserialize from JSON.  Json.NET automatically uses a public constructor should it find one.  However, System.Text.Json seems to require a [JsonConstructor] attribute (even if there is only one constructor).  I am unable to add this to all my classes/structs.  Is there an easy solution?

e.g. Deserializes fine:

```
public readonly struct Model
{
    public string Value { get; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public Model(string value)
    {
        Value = value
    }
}
```

Does not work:

```
public readonly struct Model
{
    public string Value { get; }

    public Model(string value)
    {
        Value = value
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, fixed.

Comment: Thing is there are actually 2 constructors, because public parameterless constructor is always implicitly present on a struct, so System.Text.Json chooses it. I'm not sure how to change that behaviour without applying attribute (and without writing custom converters or something like that)

Comment: You will have to apply `[JsonConstructor]` attribute to your constructor, otherwise the default parameterless constructor will be used.